# Log all authentication errors Laravel (nova)

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am building an api and my post request return the following message

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

This messsage is quite unclear. I would like to log more info about the Laravel passport authentication attempts.

I would like to log them to

> /storage/logs

Question:
**Is it possible to log detailed Auth error messages into the storage log folder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In your Laravel exception handler file create a custom handler for the
>   exception that is being thrown that logs more information. On the
>   OAuthServerException you can call getHint() to get a more specific
>   error.
>   References :

I hope Reading following laravel passport github issues will help you

https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/403

https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/289